# What is the ">" operator in a Meteor Handlebars.js template?

Tags: handlebars.js, meteor

I have looked through the source of Meteor and Handlebars.js, but couldn't find what `>` does. Is it a helper? For example in the [todos example of Meteor](http://www.meteor.com/examples/todos) ([git](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/examples/todos/client/todos.html)):

```
<div id="lists">
    {{#each lists}}
        {{> list_item}}
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

---

*Follow up*: The handlebars.js Meteor package parses the template and when it finds `{{> some_partial}}` it places the `some_partial` template. Take a look at [packages/handlebars/parse.js](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/handlebars/parse.js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'ts a partial call

https://github.com/janl/mustache.js

```
Whereas in ERB you may have this:

<%= partial :next_more, :start => start, :size => size %>

Mustache requires only this:

{{> next_more}}
```

Comment: There is also a language agnostic reference: http://mustache.github.com/mustache.5.html

Comment: Sadly, Handlebars docs aren't that good yet. Here's an article from Alan Johnson about partials and helpers in Handlebars: http://thinkvitamin.com/code/handlebars-js-part-2-partials-and-helpers